# Proving that Jacobian of Composition is equal to Composition of Jacobians using epsilon-delta

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, epsilon-delta, chain-rule, jacobian

Let us have functions $\mathrm{f}: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ and $\mathrm{g}: \mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^k$ such that $\mathrm{f}$ is differentiable at some point $\mathrm{a} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathrm{g}$ is differentiable at some point $\mathrm{f(a)} \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Let us denote the Jacobian of $\mathrm{f}$, evaluated at $\mathrm{a}$, as $\mathrm{T_a f}$ and the Jacobian of $\mathrm{g}$, evaulated at $\mathrm{f(a)}$, as $\mathrm{T_{f(a)} g}$.

I am aware that the function composition $\mathrm{g\circ f}$ is differentiable at $\mathrm{a}$ and the Jacobian of $\mathrm{g\circ f}$, evaluated at $\mathrm{a}$, is equal to:

$\mathrm{T_a g\circ f=T_{f(a)} g (T_a f)}$

As we all know, derivatives are defined using the concept of limit, which involves epsilon-delta. When it comes to the chain rule for differentiation of scalar-valued functions, aka when $k=1=m$, I am aware of how to prove it on the epsilon-delta level. However, I have yet to see the same for for differentiation of vector-valued functions - from sources like Rudin (Theorem 9.15 in **Principles of Mathematical Analysis**) and Apostol (Theorem 12.9 in **Multivariable Differential Calculus**), they end up using remainder functions without rigorously proving that it fulfills the epsilon-delta condition.

I have decided to take up the task myself and have ran into a roadblock that I'm not sure how to get past. First, let me show you what I've done so far:

We have two situations we can deal with:

- there exists a neighborhood around $\mathrm{a}$ such that its image under $\mathrm{f}$ is constant
- there does NOT exist such a neighborhood

I have successfully dealt with the first situation, with my proof being as follows:

Let $\delta$ be the radius of the neighborhood around $\mathrm{a}$ where $\mathrm{f}$ is constant. Let $\mathrm{x}$ be a point within this neighborhood Obviously, the following is true:

$0 < \lvert \mathrm{x - a} \rvert < \delta \Rightarrow \mathrm{f(a) = f(x)} \Leftrightarrow \lvert \mathrm{f(x) - f(a)} \rvert = 0 < \lvert \mathrm{x - a} \rvert$

Because $\mathrm{f}$ is constant in this neighborhood, that also means:
$\mathrm{\lvert T_a f(x-a) \rvert} = 0 < \lvert \mathrm{x - a} \rvert$

Now then, if we look at the expression $\mathrm{g(y) - g(f(a)) - T_{f(a)}g(y - f(a))}$, if we define $\mathrm{y:=f(x)}$, the expression becomes equal to $\mathrm{g(f(x)) - g(f(a)) - T_{f(a)}g(T_{a}(x - a))}$. For any $\mathrm{x}$ inside the $\delta$ neighborhood around $\mathrm{a}$, this expression evaluates to $\mathrm{g(f(a)) - g(f(a)) - T_{f(a)}g(\boldsymbol{0})} = \boldsymbol{0} - \boldsymbol{0} = \boldsymbol{0}$. As a result, we have:

$\mathrm{(\forall \epsilon > 0)(\exists \delta > 0)(\forall x \in \mathbb{R}^n):0 < \lvert x - a \rvert <\delta \Rightarrow \lvert g(f(x)) - g(f(a)) - T_{f(a)}g(T_{a}f(x - a)) \rvert = 0 < \epsilon \lvert x - a \rvert}$

This ends the proof for the first situation.

Now moving on to the second situation, which is where I'm struggling:

Because $\mathrm{g}$ is differentiable at $\mathrm{f(a)}$, there is a $\delta_1$ neighborhood around $\mathrm{f(a)}$ where $\mathrm{g}$ is defined.

Because $\mathrm{f}$ is differentiable at $\mathrm{a}$, it is also continuous, and as a result, for any value of $\delta_1$, there must exist a $\delta_2$ neighborhood around $\mathrm{a}$ such that $\mathrm{\lvert f(x) - f(a) \rvert < \delta_1}$. Choose $\delta_2$ so that the image of this neighborhood, under $\mathrm{f}$ is a subset of the domain of $\mathrm{g}$. Then we have:

$\mathrm{(\forall \epsilon > 0)(\exists \delta_2 > 0)(\forall x \in \mathbb{R}^n):0 < \lvert x - a \rvert <\delta_2 \Rightarrow \lvert g(f(x)) - g(f(a)) - T_{f(a)}g(f(x) - f(a)) \rvert < \epsilon \lvert f(x) - f(a) \rvert}$

And this is the roadblock I have yet to overcome. **I do not know how to get from the above statement to the below statement:**

$\mathrm{(\forall \epsilon > 0)(\exists \delta_2 > 0)(\forall x \in \mathbb{R}^n):0 < \lvert x - a \rvert <\delta_2 \Rightarrow \lvert g(f(x)) - g(f(a)) - T_{f(a)}g(T_{a}f(x - a)) \rvert < \epsilon \lvert x - a \rvert}$

There were two things I thought of but ultimately either cannot work or lead to further dead ends:

- I first thought of using the property $\lvert a \rvert < b \Leftrightarrow -b < a < b$. However, we are not dealing with scalars inside the norm here, we are dealing with vectors, so this goes right out the window.
- <s>I thought of using the identity $\mathrm{\lvert T_{a}f(x - a) \rvert \leq \lvert f(x) - f(a) \rvert}$. However, I can't break open the norm of sum/difference of vectors, so if use of this identity is necessary, I'm not sure how to use it.</s> It turns out this idea was false to begin with.

This leads me to the following two questions:

- **Is this a fruitful approach to trying to prove the multivariable differentiation chain rule on the epsilon-delta level/Is the use of asymptotic remainder functions to prove this unavoidable?**
- **If the answer to the above question is yes, what am I missing?**

Finally, to anyone who wonders why I do not like the use of remainder functions, it is because I often see them being used as a way to pay lipservice to epsilon-delta but ultimately evade the concept. Considering how fundamental the concept of chain rule is to differentiation, I consider the use of remainder functions to try to "prove" this unacceptable, and I am extremely disappointed that people like Rudin and Apostol would do such a thing. And the reason why I am being very uptight about epsilon-delta is because a lot of wishy-washy Calculus I infinitesimal tricks completely fall apart when dealing with vector-valued functions, and I'm doing this to try to rescue my understanding of this subject.

Comment: There is no such "identity" as "$\mathrm{\lvert T_{a}f(x - a) \rvert \leq \lvert f(x) - f(a) \rvert}$".

Comment: In "$\lvert g(f(x)) - g(f(a)) - T_{f(a)}g(f(x) - f(a)) \rvert < \epsilon \lvert f(x) - f(a) \rvert$", replace $f(x) - f(a)$ by $T_af(x-a)+o(x-a)$.

Comment: If $f$ is constant on a neighbourhood of $a$ then so is $g \circ f$ and that case is trivial. It is also bizarre you considered it in the first place.

Comment: Also, check my answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3606106/the-proof-of-several-variable-calculus-chain-rule/3606680#3606680 or here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2216797/frechet-derivative-chain-rule/2217002#2217002

Comment: You can find a careful $\delta$-$\eta$-$\epsilon$ proof in Chapter 3 of my *Multivariable Mathematics*.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a literal translation of my proof of the chain rule in my "Fundamentos de calculo" (in Spanish), which I can post here since I own the rights. In the vector case, $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ method is superseded by topological arguments since we are working not with intervals but with balls. The little-oh notation is precisely this and it is not at all informal as you believe; it really is not the concern of mathematics whether you understand this or not, for her to remain true.

**Theorem.** Let $U$, $V$ and $W$ three normed spaces, $A$ a subset of $U$ and $B$ one of $V,$ $u$ a point in $A$ and $v$ one in $B$. Suppose $f:A \to V$ is differentiable at $u,$ that $f(u) = v$ and that $g:B \to W$ is differentiable at $v.$ Then, $g \circ f$ is differentiable at $u$ and, also,
$$
D(g \circ f)(u) = Dg(f(u)) \circ Df(u).
$$
*Proof.* Since $f$ is differentiable at $u$, there are $r_f > 0$ and a function $h \mapsto \tilde\epsilon_f(u; h)$ from $B_U(0;r_f)$ to $V$ such that for all $h \in B_U(0;r_f)$,
$$
f(u + h) = f(u) + Df(u) \cdot h + \|h\| \tilde\epsilon_f(u; h) = v + Df(u) \cdot h + \|h\| \tilde\epsilon_f(u; h),
$$
where $\lim_{h \to 0} \tilde\epsilon_f(u; h) = 0.$ Analogously, for $g$ at $v$ there exist $r_g > 0$ and $\tilde\epsilon_g:B_V(0;r_g) \to W$ such that $\lim_{k \to 0} \tilde\epsilon_g(v; k) = 0$ and that for all $k \in B_V(0;r_g)$
$$
g(v + k) = g(v) + Dg(v) \cdot k + \|k\| \tilde\epsilon_g(v; k).
$$
By virtue of the triangle inequality and the fundamental inequality of linear functions,
\begin{align*}
\|Df(u) \cdot h + \|h\| \tilde\epsilon_f(u; h) &\leq \|Df(u)\| \|h\| + \|h\| \|\tilde\epsilon_f(u; h)\|\\
&= \left( \|Df(u)\| + \|\tilde\epsilon_f(u; h)\| \right) \|h\|.
\end{align*}
As $\lim_{h \to 0} \|\tilde\epsilon_f(u; h)\| = 0$, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that if $h \in B_U(0;\delta)$ then $\|\tilde\epsilon_f(u; h)\| \leq 1.$ Define
$$
r = \dfrac{1}{2}\min\left\{ \dfrac{r_g}{\|Df(u)\| + 1}, \delta, r_f \right\}.
$$
Then, the relation $\|h\| < r$ implies
\begin{align*}
\|Df(u) \cdot h + \|h\| \tilde\epsilon_f(u; h)\| &\leq \left( \|Df(u)\| + \|\tilde\epsilon_f(u; h)\| \right) \|h\| \\
&\leq \left( \|Df(u)\| + 1 \right) \|h\| \leq \dfrac{1}{2} r_g < r_g
\end{align*}
and, therefore, $Df(u) \cdot h + \|h\| \tilde{\epsilon_f(u; h)}$ belongs to $B_V(0;r_g).$ Therefore, for $h \in B_U(0;r)$, one has, by writing $k(h) = Df(u) \cdot h + \|h\| \tilde\epsilon_f(u; h),$
\begin{align*}
(g \circ f)(u + h) &= g(f(u + h)) = g(v + k(h))\\
&= g(v) + Dg(v) \cdot k(h) + \|k(h)\| \tilde\epsilon_g(v; k(h)) \\
&= g(v) + Dg(v) \cdot \Big( Df(u) \cdot h \Big) + \|h\| Dg(v) \cdot \tilde\epsilon_f(u; h) + \|k(h)\| \tilde\epsilon_g(v; k(h)) \\
&= g(v) + \Big( Dg(v) \circ  Df(u) \Big) \cdot h + \Gamma(h),
\end{align*}
where $\Gamma$ is definided by $\Gamma:B_U(0;r) \to W$,
$$
\Gamma(h) = \|h\| Dg(v) \cdot \tilde\epsilon_f(u; h) + \|k(h)\| \tilde\epsilon_g(v; k(h)).
$$
To conclude the theorem, one must show $Dg(v) \circ Df(u)$ is a continuous linear function and that one can write $\Gamma(h) = \|h\| \tilde{\Gamma}(h),$ where $\tilde\Gamma(h) \to 0$ as $h \to 0.$ The first of these two claims is a consequence that the composition of continuous functions is continuous and likewise for linear functions. To see the second, define $\tilde{\Gamma}(h) = \dfrac{\Gamma(h)}{\|h\|}$ when $h \neq 0$ y $\tilde{\Gamma}(0) = 0;$ to see  that $\tilde{\Gamma}(h) \to 0$ as $h \to 0$ we use again the triangle and fundamental inequalities
\begin{align*}
\|\tilde{\Gamma}(h)\| &\leq \|Dg(v)\| \|\tilde\epsilon_f(u;h)\| + \dfrac{\|k(h)\|}{\|h\|} \|\tilde\epsilon_g(v;k(h))\| \\
&\leq \|Dg(v)\| \|\tilde\epsilon_f(v;h)\| + \left( \|Df(u)\| + 1 \right) \|\tilde\epsilon_g(v;k(h))\|,
\end{align*}
by hypothesis, $\|\tilde\epsilon_f(u;h)\| \to 0$ and since $k(h) \to 0,$ we also have $\|\tilde\epsilon_g(v;k(h))\| \to 0,$ then $\tilde\Gamma(h) \to 0.$ $\blacksquare$